# Laravel – Get relationship count

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to laravel. I used laravel 5.4

I have this problem and I dont know where to start.

I want to count all assets in Storage where all of its category is Electronic.

Heres my Table:

Assets

```
 -- 
 id
 asset_name
 asset_type_id (fk)
```

AssetType

```
 --
 id
 asset_type
 category_id (fk)
```

Category

```
 --
 id
 category
```

Heres my defined model:

Asset Model

```
public function assetType(){
     return $this->belongsTo(AssetType::class);
}
public function category(){
     return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

AssetType Model

```
public function category(){
     return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
 }

public function assets(){
     return $this->hasMany(Asset::class);
}
```

Category Model

```
public function types(){
     return $this->hasMany(AssetType::class);
}
```

Controller:

AssetController

```
public function index()
    {
        $result = Asset::all();

        return view('asset.index', compact('result'));
    }
```

View:

index.blade

```
@foreach($result as $asset)
<tr>

    <td>{{ $asset->asset_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $asset->assetType->asset_type}}</td>
    <td>{{ $asset->assetType->category->category}}</td>


</tr>
@endforeach
```

Sample Result:

```
Asset: DELL
Asset Type: Laptop
Category: Electronic
```

With that I can view all assets.

I'm trying to get the count of all assets whose category is Electronic in controller and pass it to view. Please enlighten me I'm lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a [Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship on your `Category` like so.

**Category Model**

```
public function assets()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Asset::class, AssetType::class);
}
```

With this you can easily reach `Asset` from `Category`. Now count your `assets` in your controller:

```
Category::where('category', 'Electronic')->withCount('assets')->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response sir, I applied what you have said but i cant seem to find the count, it gives me a full build query when i dd it.




$assets=Category::where('category', 'Electronic')->withCount('assets');
dd($assets);

Comment: Sorry, did you append the `get()` method? I edited the answer.

Comment: Yes, and it works thank you very much sir @Marijan, you save my day :). Your quick response really help me grasyas.